# Having issue while while getting duration of audio play

Tags: javascript, audio, progress-bar

```
let audioElement = new Audio('1.mp3');
let myProgressBar = document.getElementById('myProgressBar');

let progress = parseInt((audioElement.currentTime / audioElement.duration) * 100);
console.log("progress", progress);
myProgressBar.value = progress;
```

In console, it's showing NaN for progress. I tried getting it by separate calculation for e.g:

```
let currentTime = audioElement.currentTime;
let duration = audioElement.duration;
console.log(currentTime); // No problem in audioElement.currentTime
console.log(duration); // NaN
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/duration) for `HTMLMediaElement.duration` says:

> If no media data is available, the value `NaN` is returned.

I believe you you are trying to get the duration of the audio before it is loaded. If so, the duration will be `NaN`. Multiplying a number by `NaN`, as you are doing, will always return `NaN`.

---

There are several ways of fixing this. Here's one:

The constructor you are using for the `Audio` element takes the url parameter and begins loading the audio *asynchronously*. ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio#return_value)). So you have to wait for the metadata to load before accessing `duration`. Try subscribing to the `onloadedmetadata` event:

```
audioElement.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    console.log(audioElement.duration)
})
```